# jquery image load

Tags: ajax, image, jquery, load

I have a code like this:

```
<div id="gallery">
   <img src="image1.jpg">
   <img src="image2.jpg">
   <img src="image3.jpg">
</div>
```

I want to show standard(for ajax requests) animated gif while picture is loading and when it's loaded show full image.

Only 1 requirement that want to preserve current markup and do all required manipulations for onload in separate script block

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ajaxStart and ajaxComplete event (jQuery)

```
<div id="indicator"><img src="/path/to/your/image.gif"/></div>
```

And

```
$("#indicator").bind("ajaxStart", function(){
    $(this).show();
});

$("#indicator").bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

When you use $.ajax or $.post it will show and hide the loader automatically while ajax request start and when it stop.

Or if you use XmlHttpRequest, you can based on readyState of XmlHttpRequest object to set indicator image.

For example:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){ 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4){ 
        document.getElementById("yourDiv").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    }else if(xmlHttp.readyState==3){
        document.getElementById("yourDiv").innerHTML="<img src='loader.gif' />Loading...";
   }
}
```

with readyState as:

- 0 Uninitialized: The initial value.
- 1 Open: The open() method has been successfully called.
- 2 Sent: The UA successfully completed the request, but no data has yet been received.
- 3 Receiving: Immediately before receiving the message body (if any). All HTTP headers have been received.

source:http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20060405/